# Table layout is all messed up

Tags: html, css, html-table

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 310px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.tabledata {
    background-color: #123456;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="allmenus">
    <tr>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="5" rowspan="2">general<br>information</td>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="3" rowspan="2">unit</td>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="2" rowspan="2">location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="3" rowspan="2">activities</td>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="4" rowspan="2">future events</td>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="3" rowspan="4">contact<br>us</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="4">gallery</td>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="3" rowspan="2">Donate Blood</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tabledata" colspan="4">volunteer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to generate a table like the following :

[image]

I wrote the above code to create this table.

[image]

I can't understand what went wrong! Look at the table, its all messed up. Can anybody please tell me what's the problem here and what should I do? Please ignore the color.

Comment: Have you tried not to use a table for your not tabulated layout?

Comment: Just an FYI: you really shouldn't be using tables for layout, unless you want to take a time-warp back to 1998.   CSS is a better tool for this for multiple reasons.  Look up some tutorials on CSS layout

Comment: In your desired output you have 3 columns for unit and 2 columns for location. But in your table you have `colspan=2` for unit and `colspan=3` for location. Fix them to match what you want and it should look right.

Comment: Please change the title of your question (be specific). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  And please indent your code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that table columns will contract to the size of the data within them. Which in the case of your column numbers 4 & 5 is virtually nothing. The table cells don't divide up evenly which is what you seem to want to do.

So what are your options? You could put a table header in and specify a minimum width for each cell. e.g. 
`<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>`

```
th {
width:10%;
}
```

Probably a better option, however, is not to use a table at all. You can space your content out better using divs and css.

Comment: Thanks a lot Leo Farmer. Now the code is code is working perfectly. I am working on css for this right now.....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the browser **can't** **calculate** the **colspan** and **rowspan**, because there is no *size to hold on*. Therefore one can set 10 `<td>` at the beginning and set a `visiblity: hidden` for them. You then have a space, but it works. (`Display: none` is not working.) And give each `<td>` a **width** and a **height**!

If you set the same class a lot of times in HTML, use CSS instead:

```
table td {
    ...
}
```

then you don't have to repeat it in HTML!

The colspan of *unit* must be 2 and the colspan of *location* must be 3.

**HTML**

```
<table class="allmenus">
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">general
            <br>information</td>
        <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">unit</td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">activities</td>
        <td colspan="4" rowspan="2">future events</td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="4">contact
            <br>us</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">gallery</td>
        <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Donate Blood</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">volunteer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.allmenus {
    width: 100%;
    height: 310px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.allmenus td {
    background-color: #123456;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.hidden td {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mawa4feh/6/)

Comment: Thanks so much P.Leger.....Now the code is working perfectly as I wanted.
I guess I forgot about the size of the cells. 
btw, Sorry for the previous title. This is a better one.